# Migrate H2 database 1.4.200 > 2.1.214 in my Spring Batch Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

For security purpose I have to migrate my H2 library from 1.4.200 to 2.1.214 in my Spring Batch application

In 1.4.200 version, all my Junit test are OK but with new version, start of the application failed :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42104-214]
```

I have juste change H2 version in my pom.xml

Spring Batch application use Spring Boot 2.1.11.RELEASE dependencies.

Do you know why this tables aren't find ?

```
 spring:
    application:
        name: myBatch
    cache:
        type: simple
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:myBatch;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        name:
        username:
        password:
        hikari:
            auto-commit: false
```

Comment: How are the tables created?

Comment: By Spring Batch, it's native

Comment: Do you have spring.batch.initialize-schema=always

Comment: `By Spring Batch, it's native`: Spring Batch does not create tables, you probably mean Spring Boot. According to the error, the table does not exist, meaning the table is not created as you might think. Please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: Which version of Spring Framework and Spring Batch are you using? For H2 2.x you need at least Spring Framework 5.3.15 and Spring Batch 4.3.5.